# How to save workspace image to a specified location within an R function

Tags: r, scoping

I'd like to save the global workspace image within an R function, but am running into a scoping issue. Here's an example of how this might work:

```
rm(list=ls())

SaveData <- function(fname) {
  # I have to use save instead of save.image due to separate constraints
  save(list=ls(), file=fname, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

# Test
x <- 1
SaveData("~/SaveDataTest.RData")

rm(list=ls())
load("~/SaveDataTest.RData")
ls() # Would look for this to include x
```

The `SaveData("~/SaveDataTest.RData")` line throws the following error though:

```
Error in save(list = ls(), file = fname, envir = .GlobalEnv) :  
object ‘fname’ not found
```

Which indicates to me that passing `envir=.GlobalEnv` to the `save` function switches the entire function's environment to .GlobalEnv. How could I get around this?

Comment: Why do you specify `envir`? It seems redundant given `ls()`. At least it works for me if I remove `envir`. And how is this different from `save.image()`?

Comment: Removing `envir` will only save the function's workspace. Regarding `save.image()`, I'm dealing with separate technical limitations (too mundane to describe here) which limit me to `save`.

Comment: Specifically, you'll see if you remove `envir`, that the final `ls()` call will not show `x`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand now. I was focusing on an "unwrapped" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `list=ls()` + `envir=.GlobalEnv` with `list=ls(.GlobalEnv)` works:

```
SaveData <- function(fname) {
  save(list=ls(.GlobalEnv), file=fname)
}
```